# SQL Server: how to modify trigger in order to avoid crashing when insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, sql-update

I am using SQL Server 2012 on Windows 7.

I am a beginner in SQL; I currently have this trigger on a table `DeviceStatus`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_insertInStatus] 
ON [dbo].[DeviceStatus] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
   -- Insert statements for trigger here:
   INSERT INTO GeneralStatus (DeviceIP, ServiceStatus)
   VALUES
   ( (SELECT DeviceIP FROM INSERTED), (SELECT ServiceStatus FROM INSERTED) );

END
```

where `DeviceIP` is a unique key.

Problem is that, obviously, it crashes when trying to insert a record/row with a `DeviceIP` value that - **accidentally** - already exists in the second table named `GeneralStatus`...

How should I modify/adapt the above SQL query in order to keep the existing functionality (INSERT INTO...), but adding also the possibility to have the `ServiceStatus` column **updated** in such a case when the `DeviceIP` value already exists in the `GeneralStatus` table?
What's the best way to write this (performant, yet safe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Inserted has multiple rows, each of which can be an insert or update to `GeneralStatus`, you can join with inserted and check based on the row exists or not like this.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_insertInStatus] 
   ON  [dbo].[DeviceStatus] 
   AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN

   --Update Records where DeviceIP does exist in GeneralStatus
   UPDATE GS 
   SET GS.ServiceStatus = I.ServiceStatus
   FROM GeneralStatus GS INNER JOIN Inserted I ON GS.DeviceIP = I.DeviceIP


   -- Insert statements for trigger here:
   -- Insert records where DeviceIP does not exist in GeneralStatus 
   INSERT INTO GeneralStatus
   ( DeviceIP,ServiceStatus )
   SELECT DeviceIP , ServiceStatus FROM INSERTED I
   LEFT JOIN GeneralStatus GS ON GS.DeviceIP = I.DeviceIP 
   WHERE GS.DeviceIP IS NULL;

END
```

Comment: @IvanStarostin - Yes, Can you please explain how it will make an impact as we are updating a different table `GeneralStatus ` or did you mean something else

Comment: _"I modify/adapt the above SQL query in order to have the ServiceStatus column updated in such a case when the DeviceIP value already exists in the GeneralStatus table"_

The update was to check if the row already exists in the destination table `GeneralStatus` and to update the status in that case and not have another insert to the destination table

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself fully. Yes, when there is an insert in the table `[DeviceStatus]`, the trigger will check if a row with the same `DeviceIP` exists in the `GeneralStatus` table. if it does then it will update that row rather than create a new row in `GeneralStatus`. if the inserted row was not present in the `GeneralStatus` table, in that case it would do an insert

Comment: sorry, looks like I misunderstood the original request!

Comment: so are you saying that when the row already exists in `GeneralStatus`, don't do any insert / update in `GeneralStatus`. In that case just use the answer provided by TheGameiswar

Comment: In case the row already exists, I would prefer to update the `ServiceStatus` column if possible... I think solution given by Gameiswar only avoids to insert (at least there won't be any crash...). Thanks.

Comment: @groenhen - I would suggest you update your question with this additional detail so its explicitly clear the expected outcome in both scenarios. Based on your comment, it seems that my answer is what you are really looking for. Did you try out both the answers?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO GeneralStatus
   ( DeviceIP, ServiceStatus )
 SELECT DeviceIP ,ServiceStatus FROM INSERTED I
where not exists(select 1 from generalstatus g where g.deviceip=i.deviceip)
```